# Finding the Projection without using projection matrix always but to use some symmetry

Tags: raytracing, symmetric

I am interested in finding the t2' with the help of **t1**, **t1'** and **t2**. 
Actually I am using some projection matrix T (this will be used to project point x and y which is clear in the Image attached) on x and y to get the points **t1** and **t2**. Again I have to use the matrix **T** on **x'** and **y'** to find the **t1'** and **t2'**. But I don't want to exactly use the matrix T to do this just to avoid the lots of multiplication.

Is there any way to find **t2'** with the help of t1' and the result followed in the case of t1 and t1'.

```
T*x = t1
T*y = t2
t*x' = t1'
```

I am attaching picture for better visibility of the question.

[image]

Comment: How does `y'` depend on the other variables `x`, `y` and `x'`?

Comment: There is relation in x, y and x' as if say x = (0,0)  then y= (0,1)
x' = (1,0) and y = (1,1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a linear relationship between the variables, you can use that same relationship after applying `T` because `T`, being a linear transformation, will preserve those relationships.

So, let's assume that the relationship you have verifies `y - x = y' - x'`. This assumption is consistent with the one you wrote in the comment because there `y - x = (0, 1)` and `y'- x' = (0, 1)` too.

So, applying `T` to both sides of the equation we have: `T(y - x) = T(y' - x')`. Now, using that `T` preserves linear combinations (i.e., `T(u + sv) = T(u) + sT(v)` for all vectors `u`,`v` and scalars `s`), we get: `Ty - Tx = Ty' - Tx'`. With your variable names we get: `t2 - t1 = t2' - t1'`. Solving for `t2'` leads to `t2' = t2 - t1 + t1'`.

If the actual relationship between `x`, `y`, `x'` and `y'` happens to be different but still linear you can apply the same reasoning to it.

Comment: T(x+1,y+2,z) = T(x,y,x) + T(1,2,0) Is it true ? If not what is the true linear combination of T(x+1,y+2,z).

Comment: It is true. Since `(x+1, y+2, z) = (x, y, z) + (1, 2, 0)` you have `T(x+1, y+2, z) = T(x, y, z) + T(1, 2, 0)`. Of course, provided `T` is a *linear transformation* (e.g., T performs a matrix multiplication). I assume this is your case because you said that T was a projection and projections are linear.